# Swift filling textView

Tags: ios, swift, textview

How can I fill my textView with restraints so that each string "test" print all the way down the textView. Example in the picture.

-Trying to match "Test" with percentages.

[image: ProblemHere]

```
for _ in 1...100{
profitLoss.text = "Test\n"
                 }
```

Comment: Perhaps use `+=` instead of `=`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add each string to previous string, run this code in swift play ground it will help you to understand.

```
var finalString = "1%"

for i in 2...100 {

   finalString += "\n\(i)%"
}

print(finalString)

profitLoss.text =  finalString
```

Comment: You are the man! Making me wait 3 minutes to check your answer. But thanks for your time & help.

Comment: While this answer is correct in a logical sense, its actual code is non-optimal. You should not capitalize the first letter of variable names in Swift. Also, this code will give you a string that ends with a line break, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @garrettmurrayThank you for code review, I just updated code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Build your string first, then set it to the textView's text:

```
var test = "Test"
for _ in 1...99 {
  test += "\nTest"
}
profitLoss.text = test
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good way as per your image that attached but you can achaive it by below

```
var strText = "Text \n"
for _ in 1...100 {
    txtView.text = strText.appending(strText)
}
```